# Could there be polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ so that $(x^2+1)(p’(x)q(x)-p(x)q’(x)) = (q(x))^2$

Tags: polynomials

I tried figuring out the degree of these polynomials.
Let’s suppose that $deg(p(x)) = n$ and $deg(q(x)) = m$
$$(x^2+1)([(n-1)+m] - [n+ (m-1)])= 2q$$
$$n+m+1 = 2m$$
$$n+1=m$$
That means that the degree of the polynomial p is less than the degree of the polynomial q by 1.
That’s pretty much it.

UPD: $q(x) = 0$ life’s good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they can't exist.
$${\left( {\frac{{p\left( x \right)}}{{q\left( x \right)}}} \right)^\prime } = \frac{1}{{{x^2} + 1}}$$
Thus
$$\frac{{p\left( x \right)}}{{q\left( x \right)}} = \int {\frac{1}{{{x^2} + 1}}} dx = \arctan x + C$$

Comment: Could p(x) = arctg(x) and q(x) = 1?

Comment: @FoorgyInfifcio Yes, but $\arctan (x)$ is not a polynomial

Comment: yes they do exist

Answer (score 2):

It is not the case that $\deg (p(x) + q(x)) = \deg (p(x)) + \deg (q(x))$. Consider $p(x) = x^2 + 1$ and $q(x) = -x^2 + 2x$. The same, of course, goes for subtraction. All we can say is that $\deg(p(x) + q(x)) \leq \max\{\deg (p(x)), \deg (q(x))\}$.

As Wuestenfux says, the key is to recognize that $\frac{p'q - pq'}{q^2}$ is $(p/q)'$. Upon rearranging, you should see that the issue is not degree, but the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x^2 + 1}$.

In fact, if we repalce $x^2 + 1$ by, say, $x^2$, it is possible to find a pair of $p$ and $q$ satisfying the equation. This shows that degree isn't the obstruction.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Have you considered that $\frac{p'q - pq'}{q^2}$ is the derivative of $\frac{p}{q}$